# Decoder shuffles JSON keys (containing dynamic keys) sequence after parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable, jsondecoder

I have dynamic JSON Keys similar mentioned [here in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/8vq9dg/how_to_parse_json_with_dynamic_keys_using_swift_i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
Using decodable, I have to generate object from json.

```
struct ChannelSequence : Codable {
    public var innerArray: [String: InnerChannelNode]  
    
    private struct CustomCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self) 
        self.innerArray = [String: InnerChannelNode]()
        for key in values.allKeys {
            let value = try values.decode(InnerChannelNode.self, forKey: CustomCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            self.innerArray[key.stringValue] = value //<--------- here I lost the order 
        }
    }
    
}
```

However, the order of Keys gets shuffled in random order.

eg.

> When I check with `values.allKeys`
>
> from [151,152,153, 154]
>
> to   [154, 152, 153, 151]

Comment: JSON keys don't have a defined order. They are like dictionaries. `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` are the same JSON. And given that you are putting them inside a dictionary anyway, why do you care?

Comment: Dictionary aren't ordered. `allKeys` return the value in an undefined order, it might change in next call.

Comment: Also, you don't need all of this custom decoding logic. All of this can be synthesised by the compiler.